# Assigning java.sql.Timestamp with daylight savings time

Tags: java, sql, timestamp, dst

I am having trouble understanding `java.sql.timestamp`.

If I run the java deprecated constructors:

```
java.sql.Timestamp(106,2,26,1,0,0,0)
java.sql.Timestamp(106,2,26,2,0,0,0)
java.sql.Timestamp(106,2,26,3,0,0,0)   //<-- Separated by one hour
```

I get:

```
2006-03-26 01:00:00.0
2006-03-26 03:00:00.0     
2006-03-26 03:00:00.0   //<--These last two are the same
```

Daylight savings occurs (at least in my country) around these times. But the dates before and after the time are not moved.  Why are two separate hours returning the same time?

I would like to get the timestamp just as my input, How can I force this?

Comment: Start by not using deprecated constructors. And then understand that, due to daylight savings, 02:00:00 and 03:00:00 represent the same exact moment at this date.

Comment: Exactly, it seems that the object created (timestamp) cannot take values between 2:00am and 3:00am. This is fine for local time, but my data are in CET (no daylight saving) and I need to insert records in that interval.

Comment: This stackoverflow post has instructions on setting the timezone: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10522783/445131

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this deprecated constructor, which is deprecated precisely because it uses the default time zone.

Use a Calendar (or a DateFormat) with the appropriate time zone (CET), set the fields of the calendar (or parse a string containing the date you want to insert), get the milliseconds from the calendar/date, and construct a Timestamp from the milliseconds.

Comment: I tried, but the problem seems to be still there. If I type     `java.sql.Timestamp(1143334799999)` I get `2006-03-26 01:59:59.999`, while with `java.sql.Timestamp(1143334800000)` I get `2006-03-26 03:00:00.0`

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.currentTimeMillis();` gives you Greenwich Mean Time which is unaffected by daylight savings, leap seconds and other surprise adjustments to the date.

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Or Specify the timezone manually:

```
long ms = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")).getTimeInMillis();
```

Source: [Get GMT Time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236052/get-gmt-time-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

The Daylight Saving Time (DST) cut-over means the **2 AM hour never existed**. So you are giving invalid inputs.

The `ZonedDateTime` class tries to help by adjusting your time-of-day input, jumping to 3 AM just as the clock jumped an hour than morning when striking 02:00.

```
ZonedDateTime
.of( 2006 , 3 , 26 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
.toString()
```

> 2006-03-26T03:00+02:00[Africa/Tunis]

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

`java.sql.Timestamp` is a *terrible* class, along with its sibling classes such as `java.util.Date` and `Calendar`/`GregorianCalendar`. Among its many design problems is is messy handling of time zones.

Instead, use only the modern *java.time* classes.

## java.time

For moments (a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone or offset-from-UTC), use one of these classes:

- `Instant` — a moment always in UTC.
- `OffsetDateTime` — a moment with an offset-from-UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds) but an unknown time zone
- `ZonedDateTime` — a moment with an assigned time zone.

It sounds like you were intending to use a date-time in your own zone.

### `ZoneId`

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Specify a time and a date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt_1 = ZonedDateTime.of( 2006, 3 , 26 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt_2 = ZonedDateTime.of( 2006, 3 , 26 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt_3 = ZonedDateTime.of( 2006, 3 , 26 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 0 , z ) ;

System.out.println("zdt_1.toString(): " + zdt_1);
System.out.println("zdt_2.toString(): " + zdt_2);
System.out.println("zdt_3.toString(): " + zdt_3);
```

> zdt_1.toString(): 2006-03-26T01:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
>
> zdt_2.toString(): 2006-03-26T03:00+02:00[Africa/Tunis]
>
> zdt_3.toString(): 2006-03-26T03:00+02:00[Africa/Tunis]

### Daylight Saving Time (DST)

We see a surprise on the third item, where we ask for 2 AM but get 3 AM back. This is understandable, because of a [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cut-over or “Spring ahead”. Starting in 2005, [Tunisia adopted DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Africa#_Tunisia). Later in 2009 they came to their senses and returned to standard time only.

#### The 2 AM hour does not exist

So there is no 2 AM on that date in Tunisia. When the clock struck 2 AM, it jumped to 3 AM. **The 2 AM hour never existed.** That day is **only 23-hours long** rather than the usual 24 hours long. So our code above asked for an invalid date-time. The `ZonedDateTime` class, rather than throw an `Exception`, tries to help us out by adjusting to a valid time-of-day. The [JavaDoc for `ZonedDateTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,java.time.ZoneId)) spells this out:

> Obtains an instance of ZonedDateTime from a year, month, day, hour, minute, second, nanosecond and time-zone.
>
> This creates a zoned date-time matching the local date-time of the seven specified fields as closely as possible. Time-zone rules, such as daylight savings, mean that not every local date-time is valid for the specified zone, thus the local date-time may be adjusted.
>
> The local date-time is resolved to a single instant on the time-line. This is achieved by finding a valid offset from UTC/Greenwich for the local date-time as defined by the rules of the zone ID.
>
> In most cases, there is only one valid offset for a local date-time. In the case of an overlap, when clocks are set back, there are two valid offsets. This method uses the earlier offset typically corresponding to "summer".
>
> In the case of a gap, when clocks jump forward, there is no valid offset. Instead, the local date-time is adjusted to be later by the length of the gap. For a typical one hour daylight savings change, the local date-time will be moved one hour later into the offset typically corresponding to "summer".

So the behavior is a feature, not a bug.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).